# How to Change Shipping Cost for Specific Products?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

There are five product SKU that I would like to add a $10 shipping fee for each product added to the cart.

**Example:**

> if all 5 of the skus are added to the cart, there would be an additional $50 shipping fee added to the total price. Is there a way to do this in Magento 1.9.3.4? If there isn't a way to do this via editing the Shipping Methods, is there a work around by creating a Shopping Cart Price Rule?

Answer (score 1):

If you always use the same shipping price for a given product regardless destination and date you can use the "weight" attribute as the actual
shipping price with table rates.

- Create a new attribute to display the actual weight of the item on the website
- Change the "weight" attribute setting not to display it on the frontend.
- Re-import product details with the new weight attribute and the magento "weight" attribute with the shipping price in it.
- Create a table for table rates and simply put values in the "Weight (and above)" and "Shipping Price" columns as 0,0; 1,1; 2,2 so on.
- Import the CSV file with the shipping rates

Please note this will add up shipping prices:
for example if you order two product and the shipping price is 4 for product A and it is 5 for product B
the final shiping will be 9.

Answer (score 1):

Install Owebia shipping extension which is available free of cost..  [here](https://en.store.owebia.com/magento1-module-advanced-shipping.html) and [marketplace](https://marketplace.magento.com/owebia-owebia-shipping-2.html) ( Don't worry about quality code as it's on marketplace)

[image: owebia extension for magento 1]

```
 "id_001": {
         "label":" your shipping method name",
          "about": " Calculate shipping fees by product as per your need  add a $10 shipping fee for each product",
          "fees": "{foreach product.attribute.sku where array_match_any(product.sku, array(sku-1,sku-2,sku-3,sku-4,sku-5))}{product.attribute.price} +10.00{/foreach}"
       }
```

worked for any formulas and conditions.. 
 `sku-1`,`sku-2` ... replaced by original sku id's
check documentation for rule [here](https://owebia.com/os2/en/doc)..